# QHBarModelMapper and QAbstractItemModel row numbering

Tags: python, pyside2

I am a beginner to Python and Qt and this is my first question in this forum that has been of great help in my learning process.

I store some hierarchical data in a QAbstractItemModel and it is working well with QTreeView. I am also succesfully using QDataWidgetMapper and selectionModel.currentChanged to map data of selected nodes to a lineEdit.

For some nodes I have 4 columns that I want to plot as bars in a bar graph.

I have made a ChartView that is working for a hardcoded set but when I add a QHBarModelMapper to map the selected row's column 1-4 to the bar series I get an empty chart.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import (QModelIndex, Qt, QObject, QAbstractItemModel)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTreeView, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QDataWidgetMapper)
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts


class CustomTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super(CustomTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._root_node = root

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if not parent.isValid():
            parent_node = self._root_node
        else:
            parent_node = parent.internalPointer()

        return parent_node.childCount()

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 5

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        node = index.internalPointer()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            if not isinstance(node, QModelIndex):
                if index.column() == 0:
                    return node.name
                if index.column() == 1:
                    return node.value1
                if index.column() == 2:
                    return node.value2
                if index.column() == 3:
                    return node.value3
                if index.column() == 4:
                    return node.value4

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section == 0:
                return self._root_node.name
            if section == 1:
                return "value1"
            if section == 2:
                return "value2"
            if section == 3:
                return "value3"
            if section == 4:
                return "value4"

    def parent(self, index):
        node = self.getNode(index)
        parent_node = node.parent

        if parent_node == self._root_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent_node.row(), 0, parent_node)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):

        parent_node = self.getNode(parent)
        child_item = parent_node.child(row)

        if child_item:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_item)
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def getNode(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            node = index.internalPointer()
            if node:
                return node

        return self._root_node


class Nodes(QObject):
    def __init__(self, name, value1, value2, value3, value4, parent = QModelIndex):
        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.value3 = value3
        self.value4 = value4
        self.children = []

    def child(self, row):
        return self.children[row]

    def row(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return self.parent.children.index(self)

    def addChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def removeChild(self, position):
        if position > 0 or position > len(self.children):
            return False
        node = self.children.pop(position)
        node.parent = None

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.children)

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.tree_view = QTreeView()

        self.bar_chart = QtCharts.QChart()
        self.bar_series = QtCharts.QBarSeries()

        self.bar_chart.addSeries(self.bar_series)

        categories = ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3", "value 4"]

        axis_x = QtCharts.QBarCategoryAxis()
        axis_x.append(categories)
        self.bar_chart.addAxis(axis_x, Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.bar_series.attachAxis(axis_x)

        axis_y = QtCharts.QValueAxis()
        self.bar_chart.addAxis(axis_y, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.bar_series.attachAxis(axis_y)

        self.chart_view = QtCharts.QChartView(self.bar_chart)
        self.chart_view.setMinimumSize(640, 480)

        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.chart_view)

        self.mapper = None
        self.bar_mapper = None

    def set_selection(self, current, old):
        parent = current.parent()
        self.mapper.setRootIndex(parent)
        self.mapper.setCurrentModelIndex(current)
        self.bar_mapper.setFirstBarSetRow(current.row())

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        self.tree_view.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.set_selection)

        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.line_edit, 0)

        self.bar_mapper = QtCharts.QHBarModelMapper()
        self.bar_mapper.setModel(model)
        self.bar_mapper.setFirstColumn(1)
        self.bar_mapper.setColumnCount(4)
        self.bar_mapper.setSeries(self.bar_series)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Qt Application

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    root_node = Nodes('Data Tree', 0,0,0,0)
    node1 = Nodes('node 1', 23, 54, 35 ,35, root_node)
    node1_1 = Nodes('node 1.1', 23 , 24 , 25 , 26, node1)
    node1_2 = Nodes('node 1.2', 24, 25, 26, 23, node1)
    node2 = Nodes('node 2', 26, 27, 22, 24, root_node)
    node2_1 = Nodes('node 2.1', 25, 26, 23, 24, node2)
    node2_2 = Nodes('node 2.2', 26, 23, 24, 25, node2)
    node1.addChild(node1_1)
    node1.addChild(node1_2)
    node2.addChild(node2_1)
    node2.addChild(node2_2)
    root_node.addChild(node1)
    root_node.addChild(node2)

    data_model = CustomTreeModel(root_node)

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.set_model(data_model)

    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I realize that row numbers of the QAbstractItemModel tree model restarts after every parent in the tree. Does that mean I cannot use QHBarModelMapper directly on this model like this:

```
self.bar_mapper.setFirstBarSetRow(current.row()).
```

What should I use instead?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks, I have now made a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm a little confused of what you need, let's say node1 is selected then what should it be displayed ?, similarly to node1_2.

Comment: The idea is that value1 to value4 for the selected node should be visualised as bars. There is an example that is similar to this but with vertical mapping of a table model and fixed starting column.  https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qtcharts-barmodelmapper-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, although the docs of the `Q{X}ModelMapper` classes indicate that they support a QAbstractItemModel as a model, they can only handle a list or table type model or the first layer of a tree type model. Unlike QListView, QDataWidgetMapper, etc. you can set the iteration point through the rootIndex property but that is not the case with the `Q{X}ModelMapper`.

A possible solution is to implement a proxy to extract a sub tree but in your special case I see it unnecessary since it is enough to iterate over the row:

```py
def set_selection(self, current, old):
    parent = current.parent()
    self.mapper.setRootIndex(parent)
    self.mapper.setCurrentModelIndex(current)

    model = self.tree_view.model()
    if isinstance(model, CustomTreeModel):
        node = model.getNode(current)
        self.bar_series.clear()
        bar_set = QtCharts.QBarSet(node.name)
        bar_set << node.value1 << node.value2 << node.value3 << node.value4
        self.bar_series.append(bar_set)
        axs = self.bar_chart.axes(Qt.Vertical, self.bar_series)
        if axs:
            axis_y = axs[0]
            axis_y.setMax(max([bar_set.at(i) for i in range(bar_set.count())]) + 10)

def set_model(self, model):
    self.tree_view.setModel(model)
    self.tree_view.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.set_selection)

    self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
    self.mapper.setModel(model)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.line_edit, 0)
```

Comment: Many thanks! So it was as I suspected - the mapper fails because row numbers are different in the tree model than in a table or list. The Qt documentation should really mention that. The alternatives I had in mind was a proxy model or iterating over the row. My real model will always have exactly two nodes on the same level for this type of plot so the proxy model would only have two rows and your solution will be an exellent starting point for what I ulitmately need. In the end there will be different plots depending on the nodes location in the tree.